# PHP while loop gettng stuck

Tags: php, while-loop

I am trying to loop through my database and add data to an array after fulfilling certain filter criteria which includes checking header data to see whether an url exists.

I see that the loop is executing the first round since i see echoed results if i break the loop with an exit. But if I don't, it doesn't echo anything and goes on infinitely doing nothing !!

The code :

```
$gp=0;
include('connnew.php');
$getpages=$clientdb->query("SELECT * FROM clientdata ORDER BY Date DESC") or  die("Pages Error : ".$clientdb->error);
while($subdinf=$getpages->fetch_assoc()){
$gp++;
echo "<div style='position:absolute;top:150px;right:60px;'>$gp</div>";
$subdinf['propheading']=$subdinf['propheading']."-".$subdinf['Id'];
$proph=$subdinf['propheading'];
$page=trim(str_replace($splchrs,'-',$proph));
$page=trim(str_replace("&","and",$page));
$page=trim(str_replace(array("---","--"),'-',$page));

if(substr($page,0,32)!="Want-to-Buy-any-kind-of-property" && substr($page,0,40)!="For-sale-1-BHK-2BHK-and-other-properties" && substr($page,0,38)!="Wanted-Apartments-and-other-properties" ){
$html5="http://www.landshoppe.com/$page";

$file_headers = get_headers($html5);

            if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
                $exists = false;
                echo "<h3>URL ".$html5." Does not exist !</h3>";
                }
                else {

                $exists = true;
                    if(!in_array($html5,$link)){
                        $link[]=$html5;
                    echo $html5."<br>";

                        }
                    }
            }
//echo $gp;exit;  
}
echo "Total Pages : $gp<br><br>";exit;
```

can somebody help me understand what is happening while I am waiting indefinitely for some output ?

Comment: Using the '@' for error suppression will hide any useful messages from you. Remove that first then come back with any error messages you see.

Comment: "does an unintentional oversight merit a quick down vote", yes as it is very relevant to diagnosing the problem, it is also extremely bad practice and I downvote every time I see it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$getpages->fetch_assoc()
```

will give you an array that needs to be run within a foreach loop. And what is that $gp doing. It is just incrementing itself in an infinite while loop. What you can do is

```
while($subd=$getpages->fetch_assoc()){

foreach ($subd as  $subdinf){
  //put rest of the code inside this
} }
```

This ensures that when the array count is over it stops the loop.

You can use output buffering to display status of loop

```
ob_start();
// Your entire function here
$output = ob_get_clean();

echo $output;
```

Check this link and the examples given below. you will understand
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php

Comment: Thanks Amit, for the suggestion. The script somehow started working...by itself ! Guess I had to wait long enough ! Only thing is, it would have been good if there was some way to know the status of the process while waiting for it to complete !